# xsl select value from node based on a subnode value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a newby with xsl and have been "fighting" with this for some time. After many wrong codes and investigation I finally reached my target, but I think that my code has a high margin for improvement, so I hope that someone can recommend a code with a better performance. This is the case:

I am receiving the following XML invoices (this is the part of the invoice that is read at this moment):

```
<E1EDP01>

  <Z1EDP03 SEGMENT="1">
    <IDDAT>901</IDDAT> 
    <DATUM>20160414</DATUM> 
  </Z1EDP03>

  <Z1EDP03 SEGMENT="1">
    <IDDAT>905</IDDAT> 
    <DATUM>20160501</DATUM> 
  </Z1EDP03>

  <E1EDP03 SEGMENT="1">
    <IDDAT>901</IDDAT> 
    <DATUM>20160414</DATUM> 
  </E1EDP03>

  <E1EDP03 SEGMENT="1">
  <IDDAT>027</IDDAT> 
  <DATUM>20160501</DATUM> 
  </E1EDP03>

</E1EDP01>
```

My task is to select DATUM from the following node:

- From Z1EDP03 with IDDAT=901 if it exist
- If the first one doesn't exist, then take it from E1EDP03 where IDDAT=027

In the original XML we may find many Z1EDP03/E1EDP03 nodes with different IDDAT values that can be ignored.

This is the code I've used and it's working, but I think it can be improved (hope any of you gurus can enlighten me):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:choose>
<!-- We first search if Z1EDP03 with IDDAT 901 exists -->
<xsl:when test="./E1EDP01/Z1EDP03[IDDAT='901']">
   <xsl:for-each select="./E1EDP01/Z1EDP03">
          <xsl:if test="./IDDAT='901'"><xsl:value-of select="./DATUM"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<!-- If node Z1EDP03 with IDDAT 901 doesn’t exist then take E1EDP03 where IDDAT is 027 -->
<xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:for-each select="./E1EDP01/E1EDP03">
      <xsl:if test="(./IDDAT='027')"><xsl:value-of select="./DATUM"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried using

```
<xsl:value-of select="./DATUM"/>
```

instead of for-each select but then it took the value from the first Z1EDP03/E1EDP03 instead of the one where IDDAT matched my requirement.

Probably this is simple for most of you, I hope someone can give a hand to improve this "messy" code.

Thanks very much in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten your approach to:

```
<xsl:template match="/E1EDP01">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Z1EDP03[IDDAT='901']">
            <xsl:value-of select="Z1EDP03[IDDAT='901']/DATUM"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="E1EDP03[IDDAT='027']/DATUM"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, to avoid duplicate code:

```
<xsl:template match="/E1EDP01">
    <xsl:variable name="pref" select="Z1EDP03[IDDAT='901']" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pref">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pref/DATUM"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="E1EDP03[IDDAT='027']/DATUM"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Whao! Thanks very much for taking the time to write this. It really helped me. I doubt between this or the other solution above, as both seem to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @IgnacioBeltran - The biggest difference between this answer and my answer is that this answer will always work no matter what order `Z1EDP03` and `E1EDP03` are in. If there is a possibility of `E1EDP03` appearing before `Z1EDP03` and you still want to use the value of `Z1EDP03`, this is the answer you should accept. On the other hand, if you're sure that `Z1EDP03` will always appear before `E1EDP03` *or* that you just want the value of the first that appears, my answer will also work.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks. Yes you're right. I have tried changing the order in my XML and the other solution brings the first value found. As I don't know if I will always receive Z1EDP03 before E1EDP03 I will use this solution to be on the safe side.

I still can't see why the other doesn't work, I guess that symbol | operates like an OR, then it's like select if matches with this OR that.

Anyway, this solution Works at any time. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply-templates to the `DATUM` of the first (in document order) `Z1EDP03` or `E1EDP03` that meets the criteria...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="(Z1EDP03[IDDAT='901']|E1EDP03[IDDAT='027'])[1]/DATUM"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think that meets the requirement. Unless the document order is known in advance.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your reply. Would it make any difference if Z1EDP03 would come before/after E1EDP03?

I have tried just using the  following lines and seems to work fine.  What exactly means the | symbol? is it like using OR?

Thanks again for your help.

      <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
          select="(Z1EDP03[IDDAT='901']|E1EDP03[IDDAT='027'])[1]/DATUM"/>
      </xsl:template>

Comment: @IgnacioBeltran - The "|" is the [union operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets).

Comment: @IgnacioBeltran The key word here is **in document order**. The expression `(a | b)[1]` will output `b` if `a` doesn't exist or if `b` comes before `a` in the input XML. The expression `(b | a)[1]` will do exactly the same thing.